# Postgres views for PII

Tags: postgresql, view

How would I set up a view that is for showing a restricted set of data for masking PII?  Can a view be created which is available at lesser role access than the source tables?  This is for Postgres that can't use any plugins due to need to be platform agnostic.

Comment: Sure, that is possible, whatever you mean by PII.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Personal Identifiable Information? cite: https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/PII and https://www.abbreviations.com/PII (viewed best with a adblocker :D)

Comment: Oracle's "virtual private database" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I set up a view that is for showing a restricted set of data for masking PII?

With [`create view`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-createview.html) :)
As part of the select statement within the View, you would generate "masked" values based on (and replacing) the raw data and, probably not including all the columns.  Unless you start generate random data, such a View would be deterministic, returning the same, calculated value for each raw value.

> Can a view be created which is available at lesser role access than the source tables?

Yes, it can.
The [masked] View should be *widely* available, the [unmasked] source Table should be [highly] restricted.

And remember that, at some point, somebody *will need* to be able to see the raw data - including the Data Subject themselves!

Comment: Thanks.  I tried it out on my Postgres instance and confirmed this.

Comment: @Martlark you might accept this answer.